# Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный подход к оформлению логики приложения, взаимодействующего с базой данных c# wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как правильнее действовать.
Пишу программу с иcпользованием WPF и MVVM, которая взаимодействует с базой данных. Действия стандартные: добавление, редактирование, удаление, отображение списка.

Вопрос 1. Что правильнее, создать отдельное окно для редактирования, отдельное для создания элемента или одно общее окно для добавления и редактирования функционал которого будет меняться в зависимости от того какую команду выбрал пользователь и от ее параметров.

Вопрос 2. То же самое с методами в Model, что правильнее, создать единый метод например AddEditDeleteUser который все будет делать в зависимости от параметров или для каждого действия свой метод (AddUser(), EditUser(), DeleteUser())

Вопрос 3. В Model есть классы сущности, например, User.cs и т.п. где лучше хранить логику работы с данными (add,edit, delete, select, filter) в самом классе сущности или сделать общий класс, например Dataworker.cs

Вопрос 4. То же самое с ViewModel лучше делать отдельный класс UserVM.cs или в общем ИмяПроектаVM.cs для хранения команд, свойств зависимостей и т.п.

Comment: SOLID же. Или я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь изучить, дело в том что если судить по youtube все немного по-разному делают, хотелось ясности.

Comment: 1. Бредовый вопрос. Вот вам нравиться сладкое или соленое? Холодное или теплое? Мягкое или твердое? А цвет какой? Может "индиго"? Вкусы разные, как и разные цели. Если вам нравиться уйма окон, делайте, или если ваш проект состоит из одного окна, то зачем вам отдельное окно? Это все вы должны сами решить, стандартов нету. Все последующие вопросы: задайте себе вот что "А дожен ли `User` управлять базой? Должен ли он иметь органы управления DB? Или, `ИмяПроектаVM.cs` - должны ли быть там органы управления `UserVM.cs` или это команды самого "юзера"? Вам выше правильно сказали, это все SOLID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В силу своих знаний:

1. Как вам будет удобно. В принципе можно всё и в 1 окно поместить (пример https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.4.php).
2. Для каждого действия свой метод.
3. Конечно создать класс для работы с данными. Не писать эту работу внутри класса сущности.
4. Отдельный класс **ViewModel** стоит делать на каждую твою **View**, а не на класс сущности.